# Right, Left, Interval, Delayed, and truncted data

Tags: survival, cox-model, censoring, truncation, interval-censoring

I have a medical data set that has all the following cases:

- `Right-censored`
- `Left-censored`
- `Interval-censored`
- `Delayed-censored` and
- `truncated-data`.

I am trying to fit this data with `CoxPH` function in `survival` package in `R`. So my question, is there any consideration I have to take when I feed the data to `Cox` model, or just use the data as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis used by `coxph()` only allows for right-censored or counting process (left truncated, right censored/event) data. From the code (in `survival_3.2-7`):

```
if (type == "mright" || type == "mcounting") 
    multi <- TRUE
else if (type != "right" && type != "counting") 
    stop(paste("Cox model doesn't support \"", type, "\" survival data", 
        sep = ""))
```

where "mright" and "mcounting" are right censoring or counting-process data in a multi-state model.

Ways to handle other types of censoring or truncation are discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530437/28500).